# ANTLR4: Invoke different sub-parser for specific rule

Tags: parsing, antlr4

Consider this very simplified example where an input of the following form should be matched

```
mykey -> This is the value
```

My real case is much more complex but this will do for showing what I try to achieve. `mykey` is an `ID` while on the right side of `->` we have a set of `Words`. If I use

```
grammar Root;

parse
    : ID '->' value
    ;

value
    : Word+
    ;

ID
    : ('a'..'z')+
    ;


Word
    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9')+
    ;

WS
    : ' ' -> skip
    ;
```

the example won't be parsed because the lexer will give an `ID` token for the first `is` which is not matched by `Word+`. In my real example, the `value`-language is vastly different and I'd like to parse it with a different grammar.

I have considered different solutions:

1. Switching the lexer `mode` but AFAIK, switching the lexer to a different mode can only happen in a lexer rule. This is problematic for this case and my real case as well as there are no unique tokens that start and end the `value` part. What I would need is something like "tokenize `value` with different rules" which is, of course, stupid, because lexer and parser act independently and as soon as the parser starts, everything is already tokenized
2. Using a different grammar for `value`. When I see this right, the approach of importing a grammar won't work, since it always *combines* two grammars leading to the same situation of wrong tokenization.
3. Creating a first crude parser, that accepts the whole language but doesn't create the correct tree for `value`. I could then use a visitor and reparse `value` nodes with a different sub-parser possibly inserting a new, correct subtree for value. This feels a bit clumsy.

If you need a simple real-world application, then you could consider strings in Java. Some of them might be a regex which needs to be parsed with a completely different parser. It is similar to *injected languages* you can use inside IDEA.

**Question:** Is there an idiomatic way in ANTRL4 to parse a specific rule with a different grammar? Best case would be if I can specify this on the grammar level so that the resulting AST is a combination of the outer language that contains a sub-tree of the injected language.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using modes is the idiomatic solution. Just requires being a bit creative in identifying the mode guards:

```
parser grammar RootParser ;

options {
    tokenVocab = RootLexer ;
}

parse   : ID RARROW value EOF ;
value   : WORD+ ;
```

and

```
lexer grammar RootLexer ;

ID      : [a-z]+      ;
RARROW  : '->' -> pushMode(value) ;

mode value ;
    EOL     : [\r\n]+ -> popMode, skip ;
    WORD    : [a-zA-Z0-9]+  ;
    WS      : ' ' -> skip   ;
```

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. I was wrapping my head around this the last 2 hours and it seems I can make it work for my real example. Thanks for writing up an answer. You got my +1 and I'll leave it open a while longer before I accept.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to transfert the decision what a word is into the parser:

```
grammar Root;

parse
  : ID '->' value
  ;

value
  : word+
  ;

word : Word | ID;

//the same lexer rules as above
```

This will parse

```
This  -> Word -> word
is    -> ID   -> word
the   -> ID   -> word
value -> ID   -> word
```

So at the level of the parser nodes you will have only words.

Comment: Indeed, that was what I did before which worked. I thought I try to clean up the token stream so I gave GRosenberg's solution a shot. I'll see what I'll end up with.