# ANTLR4 + Python - how to access fragment tokens (sub tokens) from the listener?

Tags: python, parsing, antlr4

How can I access the token `MONTH_NAME` or `DIGITS` from the listener using the following grammar:

```
date : DATE_BULK;
DATE_BULK :  DIGITS SEPARATOR DIGITS SEPARATOR DIGITS
          |  DIGITS WHITE_SPACE MONTH_NAME WHITE_SPACE DIGITS ;
fragment MONTH_NAME : 'Jan' |
                      'Feb' |
                      ;
```

In the listener I can do:

```
def exitDate(self, ctx):
    dateBulk = ctx.DATE_BULK().getText()
```

But this gives the whole date which I then have to parse manually using regular expression or other methods.

- P.S.: I can't get rid of the dummy `DATE_BULK` and define `date` using the rules directly due to structure constraints in my overall grammar which is kinda complex.

Comment: Could be handled using a lexer `mode` if there is sufficient structure to define the [guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108761/antlr4-invoke-different-sub-parser-for-specific-rule/47113855#47113855).  Within the mode, assign alternate token types to the elements of what would be a `DATE_BULK`. Will effectively widen the set of tokens being emitted and allow the parser `date` rule to be defined against the component elements.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get rid of the dummy `DATE_BULK` and define `date` using the rules [...]

Then the answer is simple: you can't. `DATE_BULK` is one token and can't be separated in your parser (other than using Python's substring-functions, of course).